# Imported SQL Server Database Username

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

When importing a SQL Server database from another machine using a .BAK file through the restore option, the process appears to be successful and completes with the database now in the list within SQL Server Management Studio.  But one thing I need clarified please.

When the Restore dialogue is importing the database a row of fields are displayed including "Name", "component", "Type" etc.  But the last field is the username.  Is this field simply showing the owner of the database where it originated from or is this value used with relevance in the imported database?

I looked in database_name >> Security > Users in SSMS but the user shown in the restore process is not listed

Comment: Database users are restored to the new server, so the users are from the server from which the backup was taken.  This can / will lead to orphaned users in your database which can be fixed by either removing them in the restored database or  copying the logins from the original server.

Comment: @squillman Thanks for prompt response.  So they are generally speaking imported with the database but are orphaned because they are not users of the SQL Server engine in the new server - is this correct?  If so, will they cause problems if they are just left alone?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.  It won't necessarily hurt, but it's not good practice to leave dangling security items.